# All fractions which exponentiated by another fraction gives yet another fraction

Tags: exponentiation, fractions, rational-numbers

Consider $\left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^{\dfrac{c}{d}}=\dfrac{e}{f}$, where $a, b, c, d, e, f \in \mathbb{Z}$ (the fractions need not be irreducible). Which are all $a, b, c, d$? Note: I'm not interested in $e, f$.

Comment: Are you asking which values of $a,b,c,d$ give a rational number for that expression?

Comment: Yes, that's what's being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can give a rational result only if $a / b$ is an exact $d$-th power of a fraction, i.e., if the reduced fraction can be written:

$\begin{align*}
  \frac{a}{b}
    &= \frac{u^d}{v^d}  
\end{align*}$

for integers $u, v$; the result is then just:

$\begin{align*}
   \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{\frac{c}{d}}
     &= \frac{u^c}{v^c}
\end{align*}$